# Create a image every XX seconds of the video [FFMPEG]

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, html5-video, video-processing

I would like to generate the following image using FFmpeg from [this video](https://streamable.com/j4wxg4)

Expected Image :

[image]

My Solution.

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex \
"select='not(mod(n,60))',scale=240:-1,tile=layout=4x8" \
-vframes 1 -q:v 2 outputfile.jpg
```

Unfortunately, the above command is generating a very close image as above but not the same. I want the same image as above.

Here is the image generated by the above command

[image]

What do I need to change to get what I need?

Comment: The first thing that caught my eyes is that the desired first frame is not the first frame of the video. Add `-ss xx` input option to delay the first output frame (looks like 1 second in or so). Other than that, tweak `mod(n,60)` to nail the interval if it isn't already.

Comment: @TheDeadMan, the **60** in `mod(n,60)` is your current interval. Adjust it to get closest to your expected result.

Comment: @VC.One I tried to adjust the current interval but I was not able to produce a similar image as expected, this is the interval that gave close to what is expected. that is why I cam here to ask for help, thanks for your suggestion though

Comment: @kesh ur right brother adding  '-ss', '00:00:01.000', solved the issue thank you a lot brother